# In oracle Is it possible to sort a select statement with a column generated by sequence?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-order-by, sequence

I have a scenario where I am using a sequence in a select statement and sort based on that sequence column. And I'm using a dynamic statement here.

eg:

```
execute immediate 'select c1, 
                          c2, 
                          sequence.nextval as c3 
                   from table 
                   order by c3 into some_collection';
```

I am getting a "sequence number not allowed here" Oracle error.
Any idea on why?

Comment: Does it give the same error if you remove the `order by`?

Comment: What's wrong with using `row_number()`

Comment: See this link - http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287

Comment: Won't the results be in sequence-number order anyway, because of when the `nextval` is generated? (I know, order isn't guaranteed without an order-by clause, but this seems more like when the `rownum` pseudocolumn is generated, from the behaviour). Do you have an example where they actually need to be sorted? ANd what are you using the value for apart from sorting?

Comment: The "`into some_collection`" bit is not valid SQL. The INTO clause is PL/SQL - so should be outside the string.